# JS to keep css selector hover state on - css animation, have tried multiple answers with no success

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

so i have been through multiple answers already on stack overflow but due to me not being *that* experienced with JS i am here asking for some direct help with my question. I would like to keep the :hover state active even after my mouse has left the area of the element triggering the :hover.

At the moment i have an animation using css which is trigged using :hover selectors, now the problem i am having with the other answers provided i think is because the hover is trigged on one element while another element animates.

Below is my css and html,

**css**

```
#offerblock4:hover+#rotategiggles {
    animation: animationFrames9 linear 0.5s;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    transform-origin: 100% 100%;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    /*when the spec is finished*/
    -webkit-animation: animationFrames9 linear 0.5s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    /*Chrome 16+, Safari 4+*/
    -moz-animation: animationFrames9 linear 0.5s;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -moz-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
    -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    /*FF 5+*/
    -o-animation: animationFrames9 linear 0.5s;
    -o-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -o-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
    -o-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    /*Not implemented yet*/
    -ms-animation: animationFrames9 linear 0.5s;
    -ms-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -ms-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
    -ms-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    /*IE 10+*/
}
@keyframes animationFrames9 {
    0% {
        transform: translate(1px, 1px) scaleY(NaN);
    }
    100% {
        transform: translate(5px, 0px) rotate(45deg) scaleY(1.00);
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes animationFrames9 {
    0% {
        -moz-transform: translate(1px, 1px) scaleY(NaN);
    }
    100% {
        -moz-transform: translate(5px, 0px) rotate(45deg) scaleY(1.00);
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes animationFrames9 {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(1px, 1px) scaleY(NaN);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: translate(5px, 0px) rotate(45deg) scaleY(1.00);
    }
}
@-o-keyframes animationFrames9 {
    0% {
        -o-transform: translate(1px, 1px) scaleY(NaN);
    }
    100% {
        -o-transform: translate(5px, 0px) rotate(45deg) scaleY(1.00);
    }
}
@-ms-keyframes animationFrames9 {
    0% {
        -ms-transform: translate(1px, 1px) scaleY(NaN);
    }
    100% {
        -ms-transform: translate(5px, 0px) rotate(45deg) scaleY(1.00);
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
<div class="column">

<a id="offerblock4" href="#">
<div class = "offer4 fullpic">

<img src="sm1611_offer4.jpg" style=" position:absolute; z-index:12;"></img> 

</a>

<div id="rotategiggles" style="width:160px; height:auto; padding-left:80px; padding-top:338px;">        
<img src="GIGGLES_1.png"></img>


</div>
</div>
```

**BONUS POINTS** i believe what i asked for is pretty standard and isn't too difficult and i wish i would do it myself so i will also challenege everyone by asking to even go one step further and if it would be possible to have js (or css) which would trigger the original animation on hover as is and then as the mouse leaves the element trigger another animation on the same element, basically allowing me to reverse the animation as the mouse leaves the area :)

Thank you all!

JS FIDDLE : https://jsfiddle.net/sLqf2zbh/

**EDIT** 
I have seem to of over complicated with poor instructions; at the moment my animation works fine when #offerblock4 is hovered over making #rotategiggles animate . What i would wish to do is include JS so when the mouse leaves #offerblock4 then #rotategiggles keeps it's end of animation position and doesn't cut back too its original starting position.

The bonus points request was referring to when the mouse leaves the area of #offerblocks4 then the animation reverses back to its original position. I don't need help with the css animation itself more so something which will trigger a second animation when the mouse 'hovers off' #offerblocks4.

Comment: Can you put your code in fiddle?

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/tour   and then read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I am sorry for my original question being messy, please see my edits. Thankyou for anyone in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea what you were asking - but I think part of it was something like this?

How many bonus points do I get? (better be a lot)

```css
#offerblock4+#rotategiggles {
  animation: animationFrames8 linear 0.5s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  transform-origin: 00 00;
  transform: scale(-1.0, -1.0);
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  /*when the spec is finished*/
  -webkit-animation: animationFrames8 linear 0.5s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 00 00;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  /*Chrome 16+, Safari 4+*/
  -moz-animation: animationFrames8 linear 0.5s;
  -moz-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -moz-transform-origin: 0 00;
  -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  /*FF 5+*/
  -o-animation: animationFrames8 linear 0.5s;
  -o-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -o-transform-origin: 100 100;
  -o-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  /*Not implemented yet*/
  -ms-animation: animationFrames8 linear 0.5s;
  -ms-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -ms-transform-origin: 00 0;
  -ms-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  /*IE 10+*/
}
#offerblock4:hover+#rotategiggles {
  animation: animationFrames9 linear 0.5s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  transform-origin: 00 00;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  /*when the spec is finished*/
  -webkit-animation: animationFrames9 linear 0.5s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 00 00;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  /*Chrome 16+, Safari 4+*/
  -moz-animation: animationFrames9 linear 0.5s;
  -moz-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -moz-transform-origin: 0 00;
  -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  /*FF 5+*/
  -o-animation: animationFrames9 linear 0.5s;
  -o-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -o-transform-origin: 100 100;
  -o-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  /*Not implemented yet*/
  -ms-animation: animationFrames9 linear 0.5s;
  -ms-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -ms-transform-origin: 00 0;
  -ms-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  /*IE 10+*/
}
@keyframes animationFrames9 {
  0% {
    transform: translate(1px, 1px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(5px, 0px) rotate(45deg) scaleY(1.00);
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes animationFrames9 {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: translate(1px, 1px);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: translate(5px, 0px) rotate(45deg) scaleY(1.00);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes animationFrames9 {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(1px, 1px);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(5px, 0px) rotate(45deg) scaleY(1.00);
  }
}
@-o-keyframes animationFrames9 {
  0% {
    -o-transform: translate(1px, 1px);
  }
  100% {
    -o-transform: translate(5px, 0px) rotate(45deg) scaleY(1.00);
  }
}
@-ms-keyframes animationFrames9 {
  0% {
    -ms-transform: translate(1px, 1px);
  }
  100% {
    -ms-transform: translate(5px, 0px) rotate(45deg) scaleY(1.00);
  }
}
@keyframes animationFrames8 {
  100% {
    transform: translate(1px, 1px);
  }
  0% {
    transform: translate(5px, 0px) rotate(45deg) scaleY(1.00);
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes animationFrames8 {
  100% {
    -moz-transform: translate(1px, 1px);
  }
  0% {
    -moz-transform: translate(5px, 0px) rotate(45deg) scaleY(1.00);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes animationFrames8 {
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(1px, 1px);
  }
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(5px, 0px) rotate(45deg) scaleY(1.00);
  }
}
@-o-keyframes animationFrames8 {
  100% {
    -o-transform: translate(1px, 1px);
  }
  0% {
    -o-transform: translate(5px, 0px) rotate(45deg) scaleY(1.00);
  }
}
@-ms-keyframes animationFrames8 {
  100% {
    -ms-transform: translate(1px, 1px);
  }
  0% {
    -ms-transform: translate(5px, 0px) rotate(45deg) scaleY(1.00);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">

    <a id="offerblock4" href="#">
      <div class="offer4 fullpic">

        <img src="sm1611_offer4.jpg" style=" position:absolute; z-index:12;"></img>
    </a>

    <div id="rotategiggles" style="width:160px; height:auto; padding-left:80px; padding-top:3px;">
      <img src="GIGGLES_1.png"></img>


    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Not quite what i was after and sorry for posting such a messy question, i have gone back and explained myself a little better with an edit to the original question. Thanks for your time so far though.